# Split off [windows-sdk] from [winapi]

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request

[windows-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-sdk) is currently a synonym for [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi).

These are different, and even only loosely related things: Windows SDK is an MS' line of software packages for application development while WinAPI in the Windows OS family's core API.

So, the first tag should be split off the 2nd:

- [windows-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-sdk) should be for questions about the setup and usage of the said package.
- while [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) -- for questions about programming using the said core API, regardless of the specific tools used.

For example, [Windows SDK 7.1 Setup failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455926/windows-sdk-setup-failure) cannot be tagged "winapi" because it's not about programming at all.

Update: due to the apparent concensus, retagging to [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: Likewise the questions [Where is Microsoft Windows SDK folder located in Windows XP and Windows 98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074402/where-is-microsoft-windows-sdk-folder-located-in-windows-xp-and-windows-98/50662068#50662068) and [How to programatically detect and locate the Windows 10 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119223/how-to-programatically-detect-and-locate-the-windows-10-sdk) should be tagged with [tag:windows-sdk] not [tag:winapi]

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely not a good idea.

The Windows SDK ***is*** the Windows API, in that the SDK provides the documentation, header files, and libraries for developers who want to target the Windows API.

There would be absolutely no advantage in splitting them up, and they are used interchangeably, both on Stack Overflow and in the broader community of Windows programmers.

The Windows SDK is *not* "MS's line of software packages for application development". That would be Visual Studio ([visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio)) or Visual C++ ([visual-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b)), the compiler ([cl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cl)), WinDbg ([windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg)), and so on. Rather, the Windows SDK provides the necessary, critical components for targeting the Windows API, including, principally, the header and object files. While the Windows SDK does include certain necessary tools, like the compiler and WinDbg, but, as stated, there are already tags for the specific tools, and questions about them should use one of those tags, not a generic [windows-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-sdk) tag.

> For example, [Windows SDK 7.1 Setup failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455926/windows-sdk-setup-failure) cannot be tagged "winapi" because it's not about programming at all.

Yes, that question can and should be tagged [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) because getting the SDK installed and set up is a critical component of Windows API programming. It's the same experts who are going to help you.

I'm speaking not as a moderator here, but as one of [the top answerers for the [winapi] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/topusers). Hans Passant, another one of the top answerers for this tag, agrees, [commenting elsewhere about this very proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369021/is-there-something-i-should-be-doing-to-advance-a-possibly-stalled-support-reque#comment597282_369021):

> That was a very unexciting feature request.  I was one of the only 3 that downvoted it.  Not unusual, the vast majority of meta visitors don't know the domain well enough and creating new tags always sounds like a good idea to everybody.  It is not, [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) experts always know everything about [windows-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-sdk), they have to.  And the reason it was voted to be a synonym.  Scattering those experts across multiple tags and not giving a chance to answer a question they almost certainly do know how to answer is a pretty bad idea.

So, I'm officially marking this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), irrespective of the number of votes it has received, because those votes didn't come from people who are knowledgeable about the domain or the implications that this would have.

If you want to revisit this, please find at least one of the people on [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/topusers) to endorse it.

Comment: _"Yes, that question can and should be tagged winapi because getting the SDK installed and set up is a critical component of Windows API programming. It's the same experts who are going to help you."_ -- It's been exactly on the contrary in my experience. Diagnosing problems with 3rd-party software packages is a system administration problem, and programmers typically don't want to bother with it and prefer to do a clean reinstall of everything 'cuz it has nothing to do with their actual job.