# Is there something I should be doing to advance a possibly stalled support request?

Tags: discussion

Recognising that there is always a backlog of work and that there may be higher priority items on that backlog I don't want to bother anyone unnecessarily.

That said, I found a [support request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362319/654614) that has been open since January.

It seems a good idea that the [windows-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-sdk) tag be separated from the [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag since the Windows SDK is the distribution mechanism for more than 'just' the `winapi` headers and binaries.  For example [c++-winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-winrt), the MLGen [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) tool along with other headers, binaries and tools are also distributed via [the Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

If the suggestion is incomplete; somehow fell through the cracks; or needs a further argument in support to convince someone it is worth doing: I'd like to try to help.  But if I'm just being unreasonably impatient I'll benefit from knowing that too.

Comment: There's no SLA on these things. I've had a burnination request out there for almost a full year (and it even had a decent pun!  [Get your \[atlassian\] out of here!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351480)  ), a feature-request that's 1.5 years old ( [Add a "Run code snippet" button to a Full Page snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337200) ), etc.. The only advice to give is "put a bounty on it", as it is any time the question "how do I get more eyes on a question"...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Except you can't put bounties on meta posts (other than MSE). :)

Comment: @Catija Well, then, I have no advice. Only plugs for my own questions... :).

Comment: Related: [*How to renew an old feature request?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364131/2751851)

Comment: That was a very unexciting feature request.  I was one of the only 3 that downvoted it.  Not unusual, the vast majority of meta visitors don't know the domain well enough and creating new tags always sounds like a good idea to everybody.  It is not, [winapi] experts always know everything about [windows-sdk], they have to.  And the reason it was voted to be a synonym.  Scattering those experts across multiple tags and not giving a chance to answer a question they almost certainly do know how to answer is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree, getting tags right _isn't_ terribly exciting.  In a not very scientific experiment I searched SO for "Windows SDK" (including the quotes) and examined the first two pages of results - the 100 most relevant hits.  Only 36 of them carried the `winapi` tag (and some of those were probably tagged `windows-sdk` originally).  If more than 60% of relevant "Windows SDK" posts don't have the `winapi` tag perhaps that tag isn't working for the people asking the questions?

Comment: @HansPassant shouldn't you be also writing an answer then. You know what happens with your comments, right? ;)

Comment: Some moderators [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41347216#41347216) a couple  (not yet 6 to 8) of months ago some regulars of SOCVR to go over the +1000 meta posts that involves tags (synonym, clean-up, burninate etc). Basically the mod flag queue went up with +1000 items based on the Google sheet we used and doesn't want to come down. Since then the mod priority shifted to deleting borderline rude and sarcastic comments both on main and meta. The handling of tag requests obviously has to wait. For some requests that turns out to be a blessing.